# Purposefully not returning child values when retrieving a Firebase object

Tags: angularjs, security, firebase, angularfire

I have a `user` object in my firebase db that contains some sensitive date (e.g., email).

For situations where I need to fetch user information (who are not the current user), how do I prevent returning this data?  (For example, if a user could view other users' profile data.)

**Options**

1. Using Firebase [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html): problem with this option is that there are ton of errors thrown when trying to retrieve the user object (even though I only want to "hide" sensitive child values under that user object).
2. Restructure my data so that public and private data are in two different paths.

Option #2 seems viable to me, but I want to check before making a major architectural overhaul that there's not an easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to security rules, Firebase operations are all-or-nothing.

As a result, attempting to load all of the data at `/users/<uid>` will fail because your client does not have permission to read all of the data at that location, though you do have permission to read *some* of the data there. Similarly, writing to a location behaves the same way, and full permission is required before your operation will continue.

To handle this use case, consider restructuring your data like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
       "$uid": {
         // Users can read / write all of their own data
         ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
         "public": {
           // public data goes here
           ".read": true // Make all of this data public
         },
         "private": {
           // private data goes here
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yea this is the route I decided on.  I think you're right it's the only way.